# Yii Framework not saving value for field to DB

Tags: php, yii

I am fairly new to PHP, and I am working on a project that uses the Yii framework.  I have added a new field to our database, and for some reason it isn't being passed to the database.

```
ALTER TABLE profiles
ADD organization_id INT(10);
```

I altered the validation, which I thought was the issue to include the field.

```
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
            array('participant_list_id, organization_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('participant_list_name, organization_id', 'required'),
            array('participant_list_name', 'unique', 'message' => 'The name already exists.'),
            array('participant_list_name', 'length', 'max'=>64),
            array('participant_list_desc', 'length', 'max'=>255),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('participant_list_id, organization_id, participant_list_name, participant_list_desc', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
            array('input_type','safe'),
    );
}
```

I included it in the form on the page by using the following:

```
<?php echo $form->hiddenField($model,'organization_id',array('value'=>Yii::app()->getModule('user')->user()->profile->organization_id)); ?>
```

which renders as:

```
<input value="1" name="ParticipantList[organization_id]" id="ParticipantList_organization_id" type="hidden">
```

Clearly there is something I am missing, but I am not sure what it could be.  I made the field "not null" in the DB, and I get an error saying that the insert failed, because organization_id requires a value.

Comment: is there any scenario you are saving with?

Comment: I discovered the issue.  Someone changed the method being called, and replaced  $model->attributes=$_POST['ParticipantList']; with $model->participant_list_name=($_POST['ParticipantList']['participant_list_name']); so it was ignoring all the other fields.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the issue. Someone changed the method being called, and replaced $model->attributes=$_POST['ParticipantList']; with $model->participant_list_name=($_POST['ParticipantList']['participant_list_name'‌​]); so it was ignoring all the other fields.  As it stands we weren't able to add all the attributes, because it caused it to save some nested data that was being validated, so I explicitly added the org ID.